# Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing this strange error while learning with my react application.
setPrototypeOf function, Is it wrongly implemented ?

```
// This ensures `util.promisify` works as it does for native `fs.read`.

  if (Object.setPrototypeOf) Object.setPrototypeOf(read, fs$read);
  }
  (fs.read);
```